# How to catch stdout of a function that uses subprocess.run() without return keyword?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

Say you have two functions:

```
import subprocess

def foo():
    subprocess.run(['echo', 'hi'], capture_output=True)

def bar():
    p = foo()
    print(p) # Can this be done without adding 'return' to foo()?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar()
```

Is using `return` in `foo()` the only way to catch the stdout of `subprocess.run()` when it's in a another function?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the **return**?

Comment: This question originally popped up when I was trying to write a unit test for a function that used `subprocess.run()`. In that scenario the return would be there just so the unit test could check the output. Nothing else would use use the return value. Seemed kind of redundant.

Comment: so what are you using **print** if you don't need value?

Comment: This was just an example, maybe not the best one, sorry.

Comment: If you need this value in tests, have you tried to mock it? ‘’’mock.patch(‘subprocess.run’)’’’

Comment: Can this help when I need to test the stdout of the `run() `? Like if my fuction calls `echo hi`, can mocking help me assert if that was the stdout?

Comment: I think, that you can post a new topic. You have to write more details, like: what exactly you need to test, your subprocess commend format ( is it always <echo> and something? Or it can be everything?). What is your program doing? Main purpose of the program. And try to read about mocking, in testing, you should cut all external dependencies.